# How to plot excel chart with multiple series from single data source

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

How do I plot the following multiple series information on a single chart:

```
DateTime                SeriesName  Duration
2014-05-02_10:21:21     X           2013.006
2014-05-02_10:21:22     Y           392.196
2014-05-02_10:21:32     X           336.168
2014-05-02_10:21:33     Y           398.199
2014-05-02_10:21:46     Z           3005.502    
2014-05-02_10:21:46     X           439.2195
2014-05-02_10:21:56     Y           378.189
2014-05-02_10:21:57     X           423.2115
```

The DateTime should be on the x axis.
Duration on the y axis
Each item in the series should have its own line on the chart.

Comment: Did the Pivot Chart not work? Or do you need additional help?

Answer (score 0):

Add a column for each series, put the series label into the first row (see below). Enter this formula into cell D2:
=IF($B2=D$1,$C2,NA())
Fill this formula down and right as needed.

[image]

Select A1:A9, hold Ctrl while selecting D1:D9 (so both areas are selected), and insert your scatter chart.